# JDBC Connection Progress OpenEdge 11.1 from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, openedge

I am getting the following error exception :

**Connection Error : [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Remote Database Name not valid.**

This is my code, can anyone help how to get valid Remote Database Name on linux server, please?

```
package connect;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConProg {

private Connection conn;

private String url = "jdbc:datadirect:openedge://hostname:50008;databaseName=dbname";
private String user = "root";
private String password = "password";

public ConProg(String url, String user, String password) {
    this.url = url;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

}

public ConProg () {}

public Connection logOn() {
    conn = null;
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connected Successed");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Error : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

public Connection logOff() {
    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Connection Closed");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Error : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
   ConProg cm = new ConProg();
   cm.logOn();
}
}
```

Comment: The error suggests that `dbname` is not a valid database name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask the person who told you that port 50008 is the proper port.
2. Ask the DBA in charge of the system on the Linux server.
3. Login to the Linux server and execute `ps -ef | grep _mprosrv | grep "\\-S 50008"`